# Add row into a matrix if rowname not present into a list R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a `matrix_1` such as :

```
    Group1 Group2 Group3
Sp1 1 1 1
Sp3 1 0 0
Sp4 1 1 0
Sp5 1 0 1
Sp6 0 1 1
Sp7 0 1 1
```

and a

```
list_Sp=c("Sp1","Sp2","Sp3","Sp4","Sp5","Sp6","Sp7","Sp8")
```

And I would like to add into this matrix_1 a row filled by `0` values with the `SpX` in the `list_Sp` if not already present in rowname of the matrix.

Here `Sp2` and `Sp8` are not present then I add them like :

New_matrix:

```
    Group1 Group2 Group3
Sp1 1 1 1
Sp3 1 0 0
Sp4 1 1 0
Sp5 1 0 1
Sp6 0 1 1
Sp7 0 1 1
Sp2 0 0 0
Sp8 0 0 0
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your input matrix `M`, then we can do the following:

```
# find which are new
new_rows = list_Sp[!list_Sp %in% rownames(M)]

# build a matrix with 0s in the right shape & with the right names
new_data = matrix(0L, nrow = length(new_rows), ncol = ncol(M), 
                  dimnames = list(new_rows, colnames(M)))

# "attach" it to M with rbind
new_M = rbind(M, new_data)
new_M
#     Group1 Group2 Group3
# Sp1      1      1      1
# Sp3      1      0      0
# Sp4      1      1      0
# Sp5      1      0      1
# Sp6      0      1      1
# Sp7      0      1      1
# Sp2      0      0      0
# Sp8      0      0      0
```

If you want Sp1..Sp8 to be in order, you can add one more line:

```
new_M = new_M[order(rownames(new_M)), ]
```